# In a Perl web app, "our" variable shared in different web request-responses?

Tags: perl, variables, web-applications, dancer

I'm writing a web app in Perl with `Dancer`. Suppose I declared an `our` variable `$var` in `A.pm`, and assign the content of `file1` to it:

```
sub get_file_content {
    our $var = <FILE1>;
}
```

I declared `var` as `our` because I would like to use it later in another file `B.pm`:

```
sub display_file_content {
    &display($A::var);
}
```

So, after `get_file_content` was executed, `$var` should be the content of file1. Before `display_file_content` is executed, I changed the content of file1, and clicked some button to execute `display_file_content`. As supposed, the original content of file1 was displayed.

Then I did the same thing as above, except that after changing the content of file1, I didn't click `display_file_content` button. Instead, I start another web request for the same page in another web browser. I executed `get_file_content` first, and click the button to go through `display_file_content` directly. The modified content of file1 was displayed in the second web browser. This is normal. However, when I click the display button in the first web browser, it also displayed the modified content, instead of the original one. As a comparison with the first experiment without the second web request in another web browser, it seems the variable `$var` is shared in both web request-response process. But why did it happen? Could you please give some explanations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"It seems the variable var is shared in both request-response processes" because it is. The `our` keyword declares a package global. You're running your Dancer app in a persistent environment, your global variables are persistent also. You're going to need to reset any `our` variables at the beginning of each request.

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite new to web apps, though I've been programming with Perl for years. I understand the `our` variable is package global and every package used in a program could change and share it, but in two processes of the same program they have different `our` variables. So what confused me may be the web server: now that the `our` variable is shared, it should be in one process. But how Dancer cope with the two requests in one process, with different web responses? Does it use thread? Thanks.

Comment: Dancer will use the multi-request model that the web server uses. E.g. a pre-forking server will spawn multiple processes. Each process will have its own copy of Perl global variables, but will also serve multiple requests serially, so if you use Perl globals that don't reset between requests, it is possible to get different ones on each request (as your request gets routed to separate child processes). This is sometimes ok (e.g. if you are caching global data fetched from disk), but you should avoid keeping session, user  or request data  between requests.

Comment: @duskast It's not two processes (or threads). If you're in development you're probably using your app with a single process server. Essentially your app becomes a server and each request executes a subroutine again in the same interpreter. Even in production with a multi-process server, a process can serve many requests and you do not know which request will get handled by which process.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's quite helpful for me to understand how server works.

Comment: The "start a new process for each request, which exits when the request is completed" model is specific to the original CGI model. If you're using FastCGI, some styles of mod_perl usage, Dancer's development-mode server (`bin/app.pl`), or just about anything else aside from a `.cgi` file, you're probably going to get multiple requests handled by a single process.